# Why won't my one simple custom user Python snippet '__init__' appear in IntelliSense?

Tags: python-3.x, intellisense, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I've spent the last two hours trying to figure this out, but nothing I've found online helps. Either all search results I've found were severely outdated, not relevant to my problem, or didn't work.

I am a complete beginner to Python, so please try to make your suggestions/solutions/answers understandable enough for me (i.e. draw them in crayon if you must.:)) I want the ***init*** method to not autocomplete all of this:

```
__init__(self, *groups: _Group) -> None:
        super().__init__(*groups)
```

I want it to simply autocomplete as "**init**()" and that's it, nice and clean for what I'm currently doing.

Searching around, looking at other python snippet extension files, and even using a snippet generator, I've
found that this should be the code that I should use:

```
"__init__ method":
{
    "prefix": "__init__",
    "body": ["__init__($0)"],
    "description": "New __init__ method"
}
```

I've created a global.code-snippets file and even a python.json file with *Configure User Snippets*, both of which are located in *C:\Users<myusername>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets*. However, it does not show up when I type out **init**, instead I still get the default suggestions:
[Default init suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1qCb.jpg)

What am I missing? I didn't think this would be so difficult.

I've looked at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets, I've tried https://snippet-generator.app/, I've checked out other Python snippet extensions to see how they were written out.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more digging around and using different keyword searches this morning brought me to [IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense), and 3/4 of the way down there was **Suggestion selection** which said to use the *editor.suggestSelection* setting. Turns out it was disabled. Once I enabled it, both my python.json and global.code-snippet suggestions showed up.